# Excel - increment a row number with a varying number of blank rows between

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to number rows but not every row needs to be numbered,  there is always a varying amount of blank rows above the row i want to number. I'm guessing I can use an "IF" formula that keeps checking the row above it until is finds a number, then increases this number by 1.

Comment: Please (1) explain what you want more clearly, (2) give an example, and (3) ask an actual question. You know, a sentence that ends with a question mark. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

If column B is where you have your Data with some empty rows, in A1 if B1 is <>"" non empty write 1, if empty write 0, in A2 write the following:
`=IF(B2="","",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)`

The formula will test the adjacent cell if empty will return empty
if there is Data in it, Max will find the maximum number in Column A and add 1 to it
you can drag the formula down